# Cronjob fails to use file_get_contents path php

Tags: php, cron

I have this cronjob that executes
`/home2/user123/public_html/points/cronjob/lottery.php`

lottery.php has code that uses `file_get_contents($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/points/lottery/jackpot.txt');`

This doesn't work, how can I edit the file path to make this work?
I'm using Linux if that helps.

Comment: Why not: `/home2/user123/public_html/points/cronjob/lottery/jackpot.txt'`?

Comment: use php's `__FILE__` instead

Comment: @Misunderstood not an option

Comment: @Dagon Could you make an example please?

Comment: no but you could read: http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your script is located in

`/home2/user123/public_html/points/cronjob/lottery.php`

and your text file is in

`/home2/user123/public_html/points/lottery/jackpot.txt`

This should do the job:

```
$contents = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/../lottery/jackpot.txt');
```